# Struct Arrays in a Class

Tags: arrays, class, function, struct

I've ran into an error where I keep getting "is not a type name" for the 'use' function in the cpp file. I'm trying to make an array of structs, to store data for "Items". I'm making a text based RPG game, so I'm trying to create an item class, that has a use function, to use the various items (In the struct array) on the characters. I've tried writing this several different ways and calling it other ways, but I can't get this error to go away. Even placing the struct before the class, in the public, etc.

```
class Items 
{ 
private:
    struct eating
    {
        int itemNumber;
        char name[30];
    };

public:
    Items();
    eating useables[10];
    void use(useables);
};


void Items::use(useables) // Error is here, tells me useables is not a type name
{
    // To use items on characters
}
```

Comment: what's `eating useables[10];` doing?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal Creating an array of eating structs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a type and a name to your function:

```
void Items::use(eating useables)
{
    // To use items on characters
}
```

In the case you just wanted to use the internal `useables` object, you don't need to pass it to the function and can just write

```
void Items::use()
{
    useables[1].itemNumber = 1; // For instance
}
```

Comment: Typing in both of those has gotten ride of the error, thank you! What do you mean by "internal" useables object? As in, ONLY that class uses it?

Comment: Also, another question if you don't mind, how would you recommend is best I make my array of structs? Just declare all say 20 of them in the .h? Or read them to/from a txt file? I'm going to have quite a few "items" that I want to be able to use their effects on my characters, but I'm not sure the most efficient way to do this. 

Currently I'm just going to declare them all in the .h, then have a menu(switch) or if statements, and depending on what item # it is, have it do whatever "effect" the item should have and apply it to that character.

Comment: @Riotson by "internal" I mean only the class can use the object *directly*, but others can still access it through getters and setters. If you don't know what these are, you should read a C++ book on classes, or look up "getter" and "setter" on Google, you will learn lots of things about classes. For the second, it's a full question, you should ask it on SO :)